# My #app div created by Vue is not taking full size of the page

Tags: css, vue.js, styles, height

I'm trying to set #app to 100% height, can't make it happen. 
Is div #app not considered a child of Body? i have this problem everytime, and everytime I have to work around in a different way.

Is there a way to completely avoid this to happen ? 
CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Nunito";
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  transition: background 0.25s ease-in-out;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#app {
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try html, body, #app { height: 100% } ?

Comment: @Anatoly yes, but for some reason it creates an scrollbar overflow, making a white bar at the bottom of the page (i have a background-color, but it  ends and continues with a white bar). i've setted   max-height: 100%; in #app trying to remove this problem

Answer (score 5):

You can use viewport height units for this issue, they work in terms of the height of the overall viewport.

```
#app {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumble here later, `app.css` or `index.css` might have traces of code messing with the sizes and properties, deleting anything that won't be used in there can fix the problem.

Comment: Exactly the answer I didn't think of, but solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is not vue issue, but likely under CSS Height % issue
You probably need to declare the code below for height:100% to work for your divs

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
```

P/S: Perhaps it's time for give a try for `flexbox`

Answer (score 0):

My task was - max Body width - 1980px. There may delete limits of width.

```
html {
    max-width: 1980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial sans-serif;
    color: $textcolor;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1980px;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#app {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```